# HTML Error - Reading @include as text (Laravel5)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a small and stupid issue with my code . I recently started using laravel after a long time and they made some changes to the syntax tho i don;t think that's the issue here . I think i made an error when writing my basic html .

my @include is showing up as text and even when i'm commenting out the line - the whole thing is showing up as text too .

(I'm using notepad++)

page.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
```

layout.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        //@include('includes.head')

        <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            body 
            {
                background-color: #B0BEC5;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <footer>

        </footer>

    </body>




</html>
```

Result :

[image: err]

---

I also added the style directly in the head to test as for some reason , its not reading my style.css file either .

style.css

```
html,body 
{
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: You mean your layout is not showing the style ?

Comment: to comment out a line in html use <!-- something here-->

Comment: `//` is meaningless to html, keep in mind

Comment: Ah thx , the <!-- commenting out works but when i load the page it shows :

Comment: @include(...)  as text  instead of including the actual head elements

Comment: other solution you can remove @ and you now can comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to comment. You shall follow the laravel way of commenting as you're already in it.

```
{{-- This comment will not be present in the rendered HTML --}}
```

However, You should have the files name with extension `.blade.php` if you want to use it as layouts or extending it. Else your `{{` tags won't get effect and so your `.css` or `.js` files won't load too, which results in plain html as output.

Refer [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)  to learn more about blade templates in Laravel.

Comment: AH thank a lot , that was it . I knew it was something small . this fixed the issue but now i'm getting View [includes.head] not found.

Comment: i have the file head.blade.php inside layouts/includes/head.blade.php

Comment: then you should do `layouts/includes/head` or `layout.includes.head`